# Trying to group sql results by name and date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

I have a table with engineer name and the date as a float.

i did the following

```
select t.eng_id, t.createdat
from JOBS t 
where t.ENG_ID in (SELECT ENG_NAME From HOSEFLEX.ENGINEERS)
```

which got me

```
1   bungle  40767.8305520833
2   bungle  40767.7657221412
3   Shaun   40825.6510914583
4   Shaun   40767.8287994213
5   Shaun   40825.6041891204
6   Shaun   40908.8024086458
```

i converted the float to a year month

```
select eng_id,
      TO_CHAR( to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + t.createdat , 'YYYY-MON')
from JOBS t
```

which got me

```
1   bungle  2011-AUG
2   bungle  2011-AUG
3   Shaun   2011-OCT
4   Shaun   2011-AUG
5   Shaun   2011-OCT
6   Shaun   2011-DEC
```

but what i want is a count of entries for each engineer per month

```
Eng Name  2011-Aug 2011-OCT 2011-DEC
bungle     2        0        0
Shaun      1        2
```

and if its possible i would like to be able to set that start and end date to filter on

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show ERD or something else that describe the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -- you can use group by on calculations.  So you can use NVL and case/when as well as other calculations and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the engineer:

```
select t.eng_id, count(t.createdat)
from JOBS t 
where t.ENG_ID in (SELECT ENG_NAME From HOSEFLEX.ENGINEERS) 
and   t.createdat > 1-DEC-2011 and t.createdat < 1-JAN-2012 -- example of filter by date

group by t.ENG_ID
```

(You can't group by engineer and display the date.)

Update:

What you can do is to group by the Month and Year and then display it.

```
select t.eng_id, Year(t.createdat), Month(t.createdat), count(t.createdat)
from JOBS t 
where t.ENG_ID in (SELECT ENG_NAME From HOSEFLEX.ENGINEERS) 
and   t.createdat > 1-DEC-2011 and t.createdat < 1-JAN-2012    
group by t.ENG_ID, Year(t.createdat), Month(t.createdat)
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what i am trying to do?

Comment: @ShaunHirst, What is missing?

Comment: i am trying to display this info in my application at least the last 6 months.  like i said i would like to display the data for each engineer for each month

Comment: i wanna put that data in a list view looking something like the following

Eng Name  2011-Aug 2011-OCT 2011-DEC
bungle     2        0        0
Shaun      1        2        1

Comment: I Updated the answer. Please letme know if it doesn't do the job.

Comment: I get an error ORA=00904 "MONTH":invalid identifier

on the following line

group by t.ENG_ID, Year(t.createdat), Month(t.createdat)

Comment: Got it to work and got the following

1 Shaun December  2011 1
2 bungle August    2011 2
3 Shaun October   2011 2
4 Shaun August    2011 1

Comment: select t.eng_id, to_char(convertfloattodate( t.createdat ), 'Month' ) "month",
       to_char(convertfloattodate( t.createdat ), 'YYYY') "Year" , count(t.createdat) "Job Count"
from JOBS t  
where t.ENG_ID in (SELECT ENG_NAME From HOSEFLEX.ENGINEERS) 
and convertfloattodate( t.createdat ) > to_date('01/01/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
and convertfloattodate( t.createdat ) < to_date('01/01/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
group by t.ENG_ID,  to_char(convertfloattodate( t.createdat ), 'Month' ),
       to_char(convertfloattodate( t.createdat ), 'YYYY')